# Control Click implementation on a FullCalendar

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

How to implement a control click on a full calendar month view.

I am on a month view and I wish to allow control select on these days rather than continuous select which is currently implemented.

Is this method correct.

1. In the day click event,after mouse down add the keypress event and track the  event? #fullcalendar.js
2. Track this control click separately,and identify the days clicked.

My idea is to press control and select the days user wants to select than the consecutive select which is in Fullcalendar

Help.